# How to use "go get" as non-root?

Tags: linux

```
$ go get github.com/qqq/qqq
package github.com/qqq/qqq: mkdir /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/qqq/: permission denied
```

I don't want to contaminate my system with non-`dpkg`-managed content, and I don't want to run untrusted compilations as root. Yet `go get` is usually primary way distributing Go programs.

How to download a build Go program and dependencies without root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure GOPATH environment variable to point to the location for which you have write permissions. Go program and dependencies will be downloaded to GOPATH.

http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH